scrollwidth and clientwidth remain the same while increasing fontsize
I have this function that increases the fontsize of a container depending on the scrollwidth. But When I print the scrollWidth and clientWidth in the while loop, it stays the same.
function adjustFontSize(textField) {
      let fontSize = 10; // Starting font size
      textField.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
      // Increment font size until textField no longer fits
      while (textField.scrollWidth <= textField.clientWidth) {
        fontSize++;
        textField.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
      }
    }

This is my html. I am trying to resize the direct children of playerInfoContainer (the playerInfo classes).
<div id="playerInfoContainer">
        <div class="playerInfo winner">
          <div class="playerInfoName">Sané</div>
          <div class="playerInfoPercentage">9 (40,9%)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playerInfo">
          <div class="playerInfoName">Hamm</div>
          <div class="playerInfoPercentage">8 (36,4%)</div>
        </div>

        <div class="playerInfo">
          <div class="playerInfoName">Gulászci</div>
          <div class="playerInfoPercentage">5 (22,7%)</div>
        </div>
      </div>

This is the css. The parent container is a flexbox but even if I change it to grid it doesn't help.
#playerInfoContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 172px;
      left: 0;
      width: 267px;
      height: 599px;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }

.playerInfo {
      width: 200px;
    }

.playerInfoName {
      font-family: UberEatsFat;
    }

    .playerInfoPercentage {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: UberEatsRegular;
    }


I tried to set the childrens flex-basis to 0px and flex-shrink to 0, so that the width stays the same.
When I am looking in devTools the scrollwidth of the containers that exceed the clientWidth is actually greater so I am only getting the wrong readings when executing my code.
Here is a MRE:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    #playerInfoContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 172px;
      left: 0;
      width: 267px;
      height: 599px;
      text-align: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .playerInfo {
      
      width: 200px;
    }

    .playerInfo.winner {
      color: red;
    }

    .playerInfoName {
      font-family: UberEatsFat;
    }

    .playerInfoPercentage {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: UberEatsRegular;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="playerInfoContainer">
        <div class="playerInfo winner">
          <div class="playerInfoName">Sané</div>
          <div class="playerInfoPercentage">9 (40,9%)</div>
        </div>
        <div class="playerInfo">
          <div class="playerInfoName">Hamm</div>
          <div class="playerInfoPercentage">8 (36,4%)</div>
        </div>

        <div class="playerInfo">
          <div class="playerInfoName">Gulászci</div>
          <div class="playerInfoPercentage">5 (22,7%)</div>
        </div>
    
</body>
<script>
     const playerInfoContainer = document.getElementById("playerInfoContainer");
     const playerInfoContainerChildren = playerInfoContainer.children;
     Array.from(playerInfoContainerChildren).forEach((child) => {
      console.log("child: ", child);
      adjustFontSize(child);
    });
    function adjustFontSize(textField) {
      let fontSize = 10; // Starting font size
      textField.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
      // Increment font size until textField no longer fits
      console.log("textfield: ", textField);
      console.log("scrollWidth: ", textField.scrollWidth);
      console.log("clientWidth: ", textField.clientWidth);
      while (textField.scrollWidth <= textField.clientWidth && fontSize < 30) {
        console.log("scrollWidth: ", textField.scrollWidth);
        console.log("clientWidth: ", textField.clientWidth);
        // console.log(`adjust font size: ${fontSize}`);
        fontSize++;
        textField.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
      }
      console.log("scrollWidth: ", textField.scrollWidth);
      console.log("clientWidth: ", textField.clientWidth);
      // Step back one size
      textField.style.fontSize = fontSize - 6 + "px";
    }
</script>
</html>




You need to give your browser time, or force it, to recalculate, inside the loop. Here is a list of things you could use. textField.scrollWidth is probably in the list, but Javascript might have optimized the actual scrollWidth out of it. Anyway, it is a bad idea to dynamically adjust your font size like this. There are better ways, but since you haven't given us a Minimal, Reproducible Example I can't provide one.

I am sorry I have never posted here. I added an MRE but I will also have a look at the list you sent me. Thank you.

Well, my idea was wrong. I had a look at your MRE and saw: 1. That class playerInfo has a width of 200 pixels as given in the CSS. This is therefore the width of the text field block as well. 2. That you stop increasing the font size when it's 30 pixels and then reduce it to 24 pixels. 3. At that stage the names are less than 100 pixels wide, and so have no change of making the text field block wider than 200 pixels. I increased the maximum font size in the loop from 30 to 100 and then it seems to work.

Yes you are right I was just focusing on the scrollwidth not changing. That wasn't the problem however but you lead me to believe that it was the font that was causing the issue. When I set the font back to the regular one the text is resized just fine. The thing with the scrollWidth still confuses me though. Thank you.

I figured it out. The problem was that the page isn't fully loaded when I try to update the font size.
Updating the font size in this event solved the issue entirely:
window.onload = function () {
  Array.from(playerInfoContainerChildren).forEach((child) => {
    adjustFontSize(child);
  });
};


I checked your code carefully and found a small logical issue. You updated font size in while loop, but it doesn't immediately reflect the new values of scrollWidth and clientWidth because the DOM layout hasn't updated yet.
To solve the issue, you can use requstAnimationFrame for updates.
I provide updated code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #playerInfoContainer {
            position: absolute;
            top: 172px;
            left: 0;
            width: 267px;
            height: 599px;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .playerInfo {
            width: 200px;
        }

        .playerInfo.winner {
            color: red;
        }

        .playerInfoName {
            font-family: UberEatsFat;
        }

        .playerInfoPercentage {
            font-size: 25px;
            font-family: UberEatsRegular;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="playerInfoContainer">
    <div class="playerInfo winner">
        <div class="playerInfoName">Sané</div>
        <div class="playerInfoPercentage">9 (40,9%)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="playerInfo">
        <div class="playerInfoName">Hamm</div>
        <div class="playerInfoPercentage">8 (36,4%)</div>
    </div>

    <div class="playerInfo">
        <div class="playerInfoName">Gulászci</div>
        <div class="playerInfoPercentage">5 (22,7%)</div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const playerInfoContainer = document.getElementById("playerInfoContainer");
        const playerInfoContainerChildren = playerInfoContainer.children;

        Array.from(playerInfoContainerChildren).forEach((child) => {
            console.log("child: ", child);
            adjustFontSize(child);
        });

        function adjustFontSize(textField) {
            let fontSize = 10; // Starting font size
            textField.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";

            function increaseFontSize() {
                // Here, you will check the scrollWidth and clientWidth after the layout updates
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    console.log("scrollWidth: ", textField.scrollWidth);
                    console.log("clientWidth: ", textField.clientWidth);
                
                    if (textField.scrollWidth <= textField.clientWidth && fontSize < 30) {
                        fontSize++;
                        textField.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
                        increaseFontSize();
                    } else {
                        textField.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 1) + "px";
                        console.log("Final fontSize: ", textField.style.fontSize);
                    }
                });
            }
            increaseFontSize();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

To know about the requestAnimationFrame, please refer the doc here

Thank you for your comment. This is indeed a cleaner way of doing it.

Hi, @clemens_blrk, If my answer was helpful for you, please check What should I do when someone answers my question?
